# Detetecting an ips camera present in my wifinet work

Tags: android

I want to develop an application that will discover the ipcamera  present in a net work . i have used JmDns and  dns  you can the same code from (https://github.com/twitwi/AndroidDnssdDemo/blob/8af540e6fb386a8f19f3422be6f8dfffffa69e6c/AndroidDnssdDiscovery/src/com/heeere/androiddnssd/discovery/DiscoveryActivity.java)
  but it takes a lot of time to find , more than 5 mints .is there any batter to discover the ipcamera

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do a parallel ping on your ip range, then use the existing code to detect if the addresses found are ipcameras.